# Where can I find appcmd.exe for IIS Express?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, windows, iis, azure

I'm trying to run the following:

```
rem %windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config -section:applicationPools -applicationPoolDefaults.processModel.idleTimeout:00:00:00
rem %windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config -section:applicationPools -applicationPoolDefaults.recycling.periodicRestart.time:48:00:00
```

However there is no `appcmd.exe` file in these directories.

Is there a place where I can download this file from?

Comment: Do you have IIS installed on the machine?

Comment: I'm running a 64 bit application with IIS 7.5 express installed

Answer (score 37, accepted):

For IIS Express the `appcmd.exe` application can be found here:

`C:\Program Files\IIS Express\appcmd.exe`

Answer (score 11):

For IIS users looking for the standard version (non Express):

```
cd %windir%\system32\inetsrv
```

Comment: how to install this?

Comment: appcmd comes standard when IIS is enabled. IIS is installed as part of a Windows Feature.

Comment: This folder is empty!

Comment: @keramat that is because proudgeekdad posted where it would be for IIS and not IIS Express